# Como determinar se um System.Collections.IEnumerable está vazio?

Tags: c#, .net, enumerable

Meu objetivo é determinar se um parâmetro do tipo `object` está vazio ou não.

Eu identificado que este objeto é um `IEnumerable` através desta [função](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74616/how-to-detect-if-type-is-another-generic-type/1075059#1075059):

```
public static bool IsGenericEnumerable(Type givenType)
{
    var genArgs = givenType.GetGenericArguments();
    if (genArgs.Length == 1 &&
            typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(genArgs).IsAssignableFrom(givenType))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return givenType.BaseType != null && IsGenericEnumerable(givenType.BaseType);
    }
}
```

Qual melhor formar de determinar se um `System.Collections.IEnumerable` está vazio?

Fiz dessa forma:

```
public static bool IsEnumerableEmpty(IEnumerable value)
{
    bool result = true;
    foreach (var enumerableItem in value)
    {
        result = false;
        break;
    }

    return result;
}
```

E também via *reflection*:

```
public static bool IsEnumerableEmpty(IEnumerable value)
{
    return (int)value.GetType()
                     .GetMethod("get_Count", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
                     .Invoke(value, null) == 0;
}
```

Mas nenhuma delas me parece a melhor forma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se realmente tem que ser um `IEnumerable` precisa ser usado e não pode ser nada mais específico (pode ser que precise por um *design* errado em algum outro ponto, então seria bom rever isto), aí a primeira poderia ser adequada, ainda que um código ruim.

Não tem porque usar variáveis *flag*, quase sempre que usa uma, o código é ruim e é desnecessário, é só organizar melhor sem a variável (em 2 linhas de código). Mais ainda, esse `foreach` funciona como um `if` (eu até entendo que foi usado por não saber verificar se o enumerador consegue ser instanciado e usado pelo menos uma vez). Tem solução melhor.

Pode usar algo pronto, ainda que ligeiramente mais lento, que é o [`Any()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) do LINQ, que fundo faz o mesmo que o código já criado. Por isso que eu sempre falo que ficar copiando código na internet sem entender todas implicações deles é algo ruim. Em se tratando da interface não genérica (o que é terrível) teria que [fazer um *cast*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Cast__1_System_Collections_IEnumerable_) antes.

Reflexão nunca é a solução. Somente códigos extremamente sofisticados ou grande gambiarra ela deveria ser usada. Toda vez que reflexão é usada morre um panda na China.

Isso significa que o código anterior provavelmente só é necessário porque tem um *design* errado em algum lugar do código, mas isso não dá para saber com o que foi postado, nem é o foco da pergunta. Quase toda situação que tem um `object` no lugar de algo mais específico deve ser uma gambiarra, principalmente com todos os recursos novos do C# que mataram quase todos os usos legítimos de `object` que existiam anteriormente.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: O código é legado, recebo um `object` e para mudar isso seria um esforço muito grande. A idéia do `Any` é boa, mas ela não da suporte ao `System.Collections.IEnumerable`, somente a `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>`. O objeto que estou recebendo, no fim das contas é um ICollection<TSource>, mas não consigo determinar qual é o `TSource`, por isso optei por identificar se ele é um `System.Collections.IEnumerable`.

Comment: @BrunoWarmling, fiquei confuso, se o objeto implementa a interface `System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>` porque não usa a propriedade [`ICollection<T>.Count`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1.count?view=net-6.0) para determinar o número de elementos contidos na coleção independente de qual seja o parâmetro de tipo.

Comment: @AugustoVasques por que eu sei de onde ele vem, mas no método ele chega como `object`, entendeu? Não há como realizar o cast de `object` para `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>` sem saber qual é o `TSource`.

Comment: @BrunoWarmling, entendi você herdou uma aplicação com erros de design e está tentando não dar canudos de plástico para para as tartarugas comerem. Deveria ter sido especificado de forma mais clara na pergunta que o código é legado e possui erros de projeto e está buscando soluções que evitem o uso de reflexão.

Comment: @AugustoVasques por mais que o background seja importante para entender o motivo desta pergunta, se olharmos apenas para o título da pergunta, acredito que ela seja clara e objetiva.

Answer (score 2):

Por se tratar de um código legado pode ser que não sirva para você, mas em alguns casos utilizo:

```
public static bool IsEnumerableEmpty(IEnumerable value)
{
    return value.OfType<object>().ToList().Count > 0;
}
```

A ideia nesse caso é converter o IEnumerable em uma [Collection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/collections) e assim conseguir ter acesso a quantide de registros da lista.

Aqui você pode encontrar um pouco mais de informaçao sobre [Enumerable.OfType<TResult>](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=net-6.0)